# Pydantic returns null value for each parametr in FastAPI

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

this is my schemas.py file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pydantic import BaseModel,EmailStr,validator
from typing import Optional,Tuple


class Student(BaseModel):
    Name :Optional[str]
    Surname: Optional[str]
    email:Optional[EmailStr]
    password:Optional[str]
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

This is my studnet.py that i included with "include_router":

```
from .. import models,schemas,utils
from fastapi import FastAPI,status,Depends,APIRouter
from ..database import SessionLocal,get_db   
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from .. import models,schemas,utils
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from typing import List


router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/create_student",status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,response_model=schemas.Student)
async def create_user(student:schemas.Student,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        hashed_password = utils.hash(student.password)
        student.password = hashed_password
        new_student = models.Students(**student.dict())   
        db.add(new_student)
        db.commit()
        return student.dict()
    except Exception as err:
        return err
    

@router.put('/update_student{id}',response_model=schemas.Student)
async def update_student(id:int,students:schemas.Student,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        updated_student = db.query(models.Students).filter(models.Students.id == id) 
        updated_student.update(students.dict(),synchronize_session=False)
        db.commit()
        return updated_student.first()
    except Exception as err:
        return err
    

@router.delete('/delete_student/{id}',status_code=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
async def delete_student(id:int,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
       stud = db.query(models.Students).filter(models.Students.id == id)

       if stud.first()==None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
                                detail='Student not found')

       stud.delete(synchronize_session=False)
       db.commit()
       return 'Student was deleted'
```

That is what i provide in swagger ui:
{
"Name": "string",
"Surname": "string",
"email": "user@example.com",
"password": "string"
}

But instead of provided values i get:
{
"Name": null,
"Surname": null,
"email": null,
"password": null
}
as response.
What should i do to get real values?

Comment: In addition to the broad exception that silences your error as shown below, you don't have to `return student.dict()` - just return the student directly, instead of having it first converted to a dict, then converted back to a Student again

Comment: If someone else would stuck in this issue, i had issue with my "id" parametr,as there was no backend for it. Just add "autoincrement=True" and/or "index=True" to your problem parametr and then create another schema, if you want some of parametrs to be autofilled(like id or data fields etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong name of your model, it should be `models.Student(**student.dict())` (singular) not `models.Students(**student.dict())` (plural).

In your code, your `except Exception as err:` block will catch the error `AttributeError: module 'models' has no attribute 'Students'`, and FastAPI will return a response with your schema, but with null values.

It's not a good practice to use a broad-except, this lead to problems like this, by making debugging harder. Try to specify the error you want to catch.